# Issue selecting vertices and edges

Tags: modeling

Can anyone tell me how to change the selection radius for the box selection in edit mode? I am for some reason selecting vertices and edges by single-clicking when I am not on top of them, even half an inch away.

Left clicking here selects the vertex as you can see.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNRkg.jpg

Comment: Please don't take photos of your monitor and then link to them in your question! It makes it almost impossible to see what's going on. Blender has a built-in screen shot creator accessed via the Window > Save Screenshot menu and you then upload your image directly into your question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Well, I initially used prntscrn but the cursor was missing from the screen capture. I don't know if Blender's screen shot function would work differently but if I have to go to a menu to activate it then you're still not going to be able to see where the cursor is in relation to what it's selecting.

Comment: It's not possible to see from your image what OS you're using (or Blender version for that matter), but if it's Windows the Print Screen key will include the cursor for me when it copies an image.  I've now seen your previous question about Blender and Martin's answer about getting used to using Blender rather than expecting it to work like 3ds Max and I quite agree with him.. If you click near to an object in Edit mode in Blender, the closest edge or vertex will be selected even if the cursor isn't directly over it. This is by design and I don't think there's any way of altering it.

Comment: Win 11. At first I'd assumed the difference was taking a screenshot from 2d windows versus Blender's presumable hardware cursor or something but on testing it, no, prntscrn will delete the mouse cursor even in 2d. I do appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean about missing cursors with Print Screen. I guess I was thinking about open dropdown menus which I often capture with Print Screen. My comment still stands about not taking photos of your screen though because you can get unwanted moire effects and finger marks which can confuse the issue.